# How to update a SharePoint Hyperlink field via a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, hyperlink

I'm using Sharepoint 2013

One great feature in SharePoint is the Hyperlink/Picture field which allows URLs or pictures to be added to a SharePoint list quickly and easily, one frequent requirement that crosses my path is the need to update a SharePoint hyperlink field via a workflow allowing you to add in a clickable descriptive text with a link to the relevant URL added in the field.

So how can this be done? By using a pretty straight forward format shown below:

URL, Display Text

I.e like this

https://google.com, Open Google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Set Field in Current Item" action to add a clickable text:

[image]

[image]